# covert label text to integer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uilabel

i create an counting animation, now i want to create an integer that will contain the value of my label text, like that: if my label show the number then my integer will be equal to one and so on.. how can i do it?
here is my code:

```
-(void)countup
{
    count = 1;
    MainInt += 1;
    numbersLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", MainInt];
    NSLog(@"%d", count);

}

-(void)viewdidload
{
 [numbersLabel setOutlineColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[numbersLabel setGradientColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
numbersLabel.drawOutline = YES;
numbersLabel.drawDoubleOutline = YES;
numbersLabel.text = @"start";
//numbersLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Ballpark" size:220];
numbersLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:220];


    MainInt = 1;
    numbersTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

thanks!

Comment: Not completely sure still what you are looking to do?  The code you have shown already counts up using the timer and the countup routine, what else are you looking to do?

Answer (score 3):

If the label only contains numeric values (or if the numeric values comes first in the label) you can simply call `intValue` on the string.

```
int i = label.text.intValue;
```

The documentation for this is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/intValue

Comment: thanks! i don't understand how can i forget this function...